# Deepest known objects in the vicinity of Capella (or, generally, any specified object)

Tags: deep-sky-observing, star-catalogues

There must be a way to do this, but I don’t know where to start.

Given a star (or other object, or a RA and dec), and a radius, what are the (say) 10 known deepest sky objects in this area, ordered from farthest to closest (with estimates of their distances)?

Currently interested in the area between Capella and “the kids” (eta, zeta, and epsilon aurigae). See attached.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: More than likely the true answer is some galaxy far too redshifted to see, without any name. So I assume you mean named, viable light objects?

Comment: Actually, I’m interested in the redshifted objects, even if unnamed. However, as a related question, “deep-sky” meaning “visible” light would also be a nice thing to know.

Comment: The Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation (CMBR) was emitted 380000 years after the big bang, which occurred about 13.8 billion years ago. The CMBR is a named object in the sense that it does have a name. It's everywhere and anywhere one looks.

Comment: @David, interesting, yes, of course. (You got me on that one, good call.) But inside of the CMBR, what are the next (say) 9 most distant objects?

Comment: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/conesearch

Comment: This is within the Milky Way "zone of avoidance",  You won't see many background galaxies through all the fog of stars, dust, gas etc in the milky way.

Comment: @James - excellent point, I hadn’t thought of that. Results definitely come with an asterisk and a caveat.

Comment: It seems the “conesearch” link suggested by @Leos will give the desired DSOs (red shifts are included in the return table). And, Gaia EDR3 probably covers (at least) the visible stars. Is there some kind of a tool for querying EDR3 — anyone with experience trying this?

Comment: @BruceSimonson You can query the Gaia tables at the [Gaia archive](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/). There is a drop down to select what you want to query which defaults to the DR3 source table since that's the one that is most useful for most people